# Integration of JSF and Ext GWT

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, gxt

I am enhancing an existing JSF app. There I need to add ExtGWT component to the existing JSF based GUI. Is it possible to integrate JSF and Ext GWT? If not do I have any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible [ExtJS GWT with JSF?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?54187-ExtJS-GWT-with-JSF)(haven't tried myself..)

INMO if you want to enrich you current JSF application you better look at JSF Component library's like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableComplex.jsf) <- this  is example of their table...

also there is this project [Integrating the Google Web Toolkit with JSF using G4jsf](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365076/Integrating-the-Google-Web-Toolkit-with-JSF-using-G4jsf) , not sure how active it is