# can i use a gwt library in a jsf project

Tags: jsf, gwt, cordova, primefaces, gwt2

I want to create a mobile app using PrimeFaces. In it, I also want to use Phonegap, but not directly, rather through its GWT abstraction- phonegap-gwt.

Some of the features provided by PhoneGap, in a phonegap application, require the web page accessing the phone's functionality to be a local page(on the device where phone's functionality is to be accessed)... this can be done using phonegap-gwt in a google web toolkit project also, i.e. dont put server side code in the page that utilises phonegap-gwt code(correct me if I am wrong here, so far?)... On the other hand, the program created by jsf(i.e. primefaces) is a mobile web application.

Hence, what I am confused about is, can I keep GWT code (for Phonegap access through GWT) and JSF code in the same project? I understand that the phonegap gwt code will get compiled into Javascript, but can such programming,i.e. keeping gwt code with jsf code, be implemented? Even if this is possible theoretically, wont there be issues/restrictions that I would have to keep track of? What are those restrictions? Have you tried combining GWT code with JSF code? Did it work?

Comment: It should be possible , look here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9920285/617373